# How do I add a addHeaderView to a list view?

Tags: android, listview

I would like to add a header to a list.  This is what I now have:

```
    header = "My header";
    txtV = (TextView) buildHeader(header);
    lv.addHeaderView(txtV );
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mTitle));
```

and

```
private View buildHeader(String header) {
    TextView txt=new TextView(this);
    txt.setClickable(false);
    txt.setGravity(CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    txt.setText(header); 
    return txt;
}
```

This works, sort of. My problems now are: 1 The header is not fixed at the top, it scrolls off. 2 The header is clickable which it should not be. Also the header is position 0 in the listAdapter, which throws off the count. 
The txtV is brought out so I can change the header as required.

Thanks
Cliff

Comment: I found my problem. Well I finally found an example of how it should be done. 
lv.addHeaderView( buildHeader());
 and
    private View buildHeader() {
     TextView txt=new TextView(this);
     txt.setText(header);       
        return(txt); }
Thanks for your time. 
 Cliff

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do:

```
View myHeaderView = ...; // your view
lv.setHeaderView(myHeaderView);
```

What your code does is trying to tell the `ListView` to use itself as its header, which is clearly not got going to work :) The 2nd parameter is the data associated with your header, and is usually only needed if your header is clickable.

Comment: Yea. I still don't what data is.  I want the it to be non-clickable.   Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a simple list like that, define the header in setListAdapter, where you have the word "titles". Be careful, because you need to use a char sequence instead of a string. This code works:

```
String[] header ={"my header"}; 
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,              
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, header));
```

Also, be sure your main.xml file is correct. I just copied the first one from here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: Well I do not want the header to be part of the list.  There is no x.xml file.  I am building this on the fly.  But thanks for the input.